# Spring + Websphere 8.5: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction]

Tags: java, rmi, spring-transactions, websphere-8

There is a Websphere AS 8.5 where runs XA Datasource. Also there is a Spring application which must work in this environment and connect to the datasource. An application context is loaded by a servlet and the application uses `RmiExporters` to provide RMI access to some services (which are shared in the separate thread) and all DAOs' methods are marked with `@Transactional`.

If I try to write something to the database from the main thread (e.g. during initialization of any class), it works properly. But if I try to write (or read with HQL SELECT-query) something via RMI invokation I see an exception:

```
org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction]
at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter.<init>(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:156)
at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter.<init>(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:152)
at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.getTransaction(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:124)
at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.getStatus(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:119)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:73)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:115)
at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.TransactionManagerBasedSynchronizationStrategy.canRegisterSynchronization(TransactionManagerBasedSynchronizationStrategy.java:56)
at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.canRegisterSynchronization(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:148)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.attemptToRegisterJtaSync(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:240)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.pulse(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:268)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1202)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:179)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:174)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEMFactory.createEntityManager(JPAEMFactory.java:297)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:202)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:211)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy414.persist(Unknown Source)
```

Actual configuration is the following:

persistence unit in the persistence.xml:

```xml
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/oracledatasource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="connection.pool.size" value="5" />
        <property name="current_session_context_class" value="managed" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
    </properties>
```

Spring configuration looks like this:

```xml
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="persistenceUnits">
        <map>
            <entry key="pu1" value="persistence/pu1" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/pu1"/>
```

What can I try to fix this problem?

Comment: Is there a nested exception from Hibernate that shows what problem actually occurred?  Can you modify the code to add extra diagnostics?

Comment: No, this was the actual error. The diagnostics shows that `java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction` lives in the thread which is managed by JavaEE container (Websphere in this case), but `RmiExpoter` lives in another thread where there is no context with such kind of transactions. Hope it will be enough so far.

Comment: Ah, I was missing the subtlety of off-main-thread in your explanation.  I don't know enough about Spring/Hibernate to know if there's an existing fix, but I'd suggest changing the Hibernate code to perform the lookup from the main thread and then save the ExtendedJTATransaction object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution was to use `JPATransactionManager` of Spring with `LOCAL_RESOURCE` persistence unit.